# find extremums of $x^2+y^2-12x+16y$ on compact set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to find the max/min points of the function \begin{equation*}f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-12x+16y\end{equation*} on the set \begin{equation*}D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq1\space,\space 3x\geq -y\}\end{equation*}
I noticed that for each $x\in int(D)\space \nabla f(x)\not=0$ so the max/min points must be on $\partial D$.
I couldn't think of a way to find those points without getting into too many calculations. for example I tried using Lagrange multipliers to find the max/min points on $S^1$ and  on the line $y=-3x$. this gave me the minimum of $f$ on $D$ but the maximum still remains a mystery. 
 is there a friendlier way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to rewrite the function as
$$f(x,y)=(x-6)^2+(y+8)^2-100, $$
and think about the points in $D$ closest/furthest from $(6,-8)$.

Comment: That's a nice call